# How to make an object from a Dynamic dictionary swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, object, nsdictionary

This is my json:

```
"latest_receipt_info" =     (
            {
        "expires_date" = "2022-02-15 07:33:27 Etc/GMT";
        "is_in_intro_offer_period" = false;
        "is_trial_period" = false;
        "product_id" = "com.apollo66.InAppPurchasePT.AutoRenewableGroup.ARenewable6";
        "transaction_id" = 1000000968989231;
        "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000072680194;
    },
            {
        "expires_date" = "2022-02-15 07:33:27 Etc/GMT";
        "is_in_intro_offer_period" = false;
        "is_trial_period" = false;
        "product_id" = "com.apollo66.InAppPurchasePT.AutoRenewableGroup.ARenewable6";
        "transaction_id" = 1000000968989231;
        "web_order_line_item_id" = 1000000072680194;
        "cancellation_date" = "2019-12-05 19:14:48 Etc/GMT",
    }
);
```

As you can see there are 1 extra attributes in the 1st dictionary. Now I want to make an object for this kind of dictionary where sometimes "cancellation_date": "***" attribute could appear and sometimes not. How can I do it?

This is my object:

```
struct LatestReceiptInfo {
    var expiresDate: Date? = nil
    let isInIntroOfferPeriod: Bool
    let isTrialPeriod: Bool
    let productId : String
    var cancellationDate: Date? = nil
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to bind the values:

```
for receiptInf in receiptInfo {
    let recInf = receiptInf as! NSDictionary
    guard let expiresDate = recInf["expires_date"] as? Date,
          let isInIntroOfferPeriod = recInf["is_in_intro_offer_period"] as? Bool,
          let isTrialPeriod = recInf["is_trial_period"] as? Bool,
          let productId = recInf["product_id"] as? String else {
              print("Something is not well")
              continue
          }
    let latestReceiptInfo = LatestReceiptInfo(expiresDate: expiresDate, isInIntroOfferPeriod: isInIntroOfferPeriod, isTrialPeriod: isTrialPeriod, productId: productId, cancellationDate: nil)
    latestReceiptInfoArray.append(latestReceiptInfo)
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: You have declared your custom type to conform to Codable but the code seems to have used something else to parse the json, why aren't you making use of Codable?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with notes

1- Any json should be surrounded with `{}` or `[]` and yours isn't

2- You have an invalid json

```
 "product_id" = "com.com.ARenewable6"; // = should be : and ; should be ,
```

3- You make a bool a string with "false" while it should be false

4- For supporting properties without _ you need to set `keyDecodingStrategy` to `.convertFromSnakeCase` and

5- For supporting string dates you need to assign a formatter to `dateDecodingStrategy`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        let str = """
{
"latest_receipt_info": [
{
    "expires_date": "2019-12-10 17:37:05 Etc/GMT",
    "is_in_intro_offer_period": false,
    "is_trial_period": false,
    "product_id":"com.com.ARenewable6",
    "cancellation_date": "2019-12-05 19:14:48 Etc/GMT"
}
]}

"""
        
        do  {
            
          //  let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: receiptInfo, options: [:])
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            let form = DateFormatter()
            form.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV"
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(form)
            let res = try decoder.decode([String:[LatestReceiptInfo]].self, from: Data(str.utf8))
            
            print(res)
        }
        catch {
            
            print(error)
        }
        
        
        
        
    }


}



struct LatestReceiptInfo: Codable {
    var expiresDate: Date? = nil
    let isInIntroOfferPeriod: Bool
    let isTrialPeriod: Bool
    let productId : String
    var cancellationDate: Date? = nil
}
```

Comment: My apology. I was in hurry. I have updated the response. I actually copied the response from a long list. My main concern is to make an object from this kind of array where an attribute can be missing sometimes. Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: so this is a  printed dictionary not json ?

Comment: Yes, it is printed.

Comment: BTw make use of `//  let data = try JSONSerialization.data(wit` in answer to convert the dictionary to data and decode it

Comment: Yes it is done. `let requestData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have made stack.json file and add it to our project file by dragging it to file project

```
{
  "latest_receipt_info": [
    {
      "expires_date": "2019-12-10 17:37:05 Etc/GMT",
      "is_in_intro_offer_period": false,
      "is_trial_period": false,
      "product_id": "com.com.ARenewable6",
      "cancellation_date": "2019-12-05 19:14:48 Etc/GMT"
    },
    {
      "expires_date": "2019-12-10 17:37:05 Etc/GMT",
      "is_in_intro_offer_period": false,
      "is_trial_period": false,
      "product_id": "com.com.ARenewable6"
    }
  ]
}
```

for simplicity, I m naming variable as the same described in the JSON, though you can choose your own name for your modal class

```
struct JSONModal : Codable {
    var latest_receipt_info : [LatestReceiptInfo]
}

struct LatestReceiptInfo: Codable {
    var expires_date: Date? = nil
    let is_in_intro_offer_period: Bool
    let is_trial_period: Bool
    let product_id : String
    var cancellation_date: Date? = nil
}
```

1-> now first we want to load this json file from our project in real life project you will load it from web or some API call

```
    guard let jsonUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "stack", withExtension: "json") else {
        fatalError("sorry this file doesnt exist")
    }
    guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: jsonUrl) else {
        fatalError("json url may be currupted I m unable to produce Data out of url")
    }
```

at this point, you have a Data object with JSON store in it
its time to decode it

```
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    
    let form = DateFormatter()
    form.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss VV" //thanks sh_khan for this
    jsonDecoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(form)

    guard let json = try? jsonDecoder.decode(JSONModal.self, from: data) else {
        fatalError("sorry unable to get json from given data may happen the model yiu have creatd have some problem")
    }
```

now when decode will not find any data like in our case one of the entries doesn't have a cancellation date then it will give nil

so we have our JSON lets print it

```
print("json is \(json)")
```